# Comparing two FluentWebElement

Tags: java, selenium

I am working with selenium and I want to compare 2 FluentWebElement like this:

```
Component component el(Util.getGwtIdWithHash(id.toString())).as(classType);
FluentWebElement element1 = newFluent(component.getElement());

WebElement focusWebElement = dialog.getDriver().switchTo().activeElement();
FluentWebElement element2= newFluent(focusWebElement);

element1.equals(element2);
```

The `.equals` gives me false while they are having the same HTML but

```
element1.getElement().equals(element2.getElement());
```

Gives me true. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

In Java, If we compare two objects then it will check for the hashcode of the objects are equals or not. ie, if two reference are pointing to same object then it will returns true otherwise false.

Here, element1 and element2 are different references and those are pointing same web Element. so that, element1.equals(element2) returns false.